# Xtext: define syntactic sugar for DSL

Tags: syntax, dsl, xtext, language-design, syntactic-sugar

Is it possible to define some kind of rewrite rules for syntactic sugar for an Xtext DSL? (e.g. similar to how [Spoofax](http://www.metaborg.org/en/latest/source/langdev/meta/lang/stratego/strategoxt/04-term-rewriting.html) handles it)

Let me demonstrate with an example: suppose we have a dummy expression language for booleans and lists. Informally:

1. Boolean literals: `True` and `False`
2. Boolean negation: `not <E>`
3. Conditional expressions: `if <E> then <E> else <E>`
4. List literals: `[<E>, ..., <E>]`
5. Check for non-empty lists: `<E> exists`

An example program would be something like

```
if [] exists then [not True] else [if True then False else True, [False, True]]
```

There are three kind of syntactic sugars I could add to this language.

1. **Synonyms**: write `empty` instead of `[]`.
2. **Default values**: automatically convert `if <E> then <E>` to `if <E> then <E> else empty`. I.e. the `else` branch should by default contain the value `empty`.
3. **Defining new syntactic constructs in terms of others**: e.g. define `<E> is absent` as `not (<E> exists)`.

The idea is that I don't have to worry about these constructs in later steps when writing the code generator or type system. For example, the type of a term `[] is absent` should be automatically typed by the typing rules of `not <E>` and `<E> exists`, without having to define a separate typing rule for this.

What is the best way to achieve this with Xtext?

Comment: I don't understand your question, with Xtext you define a concrete textual syntax so you can choose to have 1000 concrete textual ways to define the exact same AST element if you wish to. You may need to define your own metamodel instead of letting Xtext generate it based on the rules you define (by default Xtext will generate roughly an AST concept per rule basically)

Comment: @user1292456 Okay, you got me thinking. My first example now seems easy. I can just add a simple action to define an `empty` synonym that returns a list literal (i.e. `EmptyLiteral: {ListLiteral} 'empty';`). For the second, I guess a custom metamodel could work. I have no experience with that though, so I will need to look that up. Still, for the third one I'm not so sure. Is it somehow possible to create two AST elements (e.g. a `NotExpression` containing an `ExistsExpression`) from just one rule?

Comment: Looks doable but requires additional tweaking: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/659086/